# É possivel adcionar uma view com express-generator?

Tags: node.js, scaffold, partial

Gostaria de entender se após a criação da estrutura de um projeto com `express -v pug -c sass projectoName`, é possivel adicionar alguma view ou partial, para ser usando como header ou footer.

Em resumo, como adcionar novas páginas com express-generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O express generator é um ferramenta para criação e configuração inicial de um app. Ele cria as estruturas básicas da aplicação, configura a engine de visualização, a engine css, dente outros, mas termina nisto.

Uma vez que o comando `express -v pug -c sass projectoName` é executado, o express-generator finaliza o seu trabalho.

Para criar novas visualizações (views), completas ou parciais, é necessário criar um novo arquivo manualmente.

Frameworks como Ruby on Rails, por exemplo, podem gerar views, models ou estruturar (scaffold) um CRUD completo.

Há outros frameworks, como Sails,js (baseado em express.js), quem tem o comando `sails generate page` o qual faz o que é proposto na pergunta: Criar uma view a estrutura dela.